# Is there a way to specify a default value for python enums?

Tags: python, enums

Given the following enum:

```
class MyEnum(IntEnum):

    A = 0
    B = 1
    C = 2
```

How can I specify a default value. I want to be able to do:

```
my_val = MyEnum()
```

and have`my_val` be `<MyEnum.A: 0>`

Is this possible? I've tried customizing `__new__`, `__init__`, `__call__` but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You want `my_val` to be the enum value `A`? Don't you want `my_val` to be an instance of `MyEnum`?

Comment: @ChristianDean I want to do `my_val = MyEnum()` and have the result be the same as doing `my_val = MyEnum(0)`

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://ideone.com/mKk5nF or http://ideone.com/mfW9Jr

Comment: @falsetru Yup, that second link is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You may use `_missing_` function; According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)" `_missing_ `– a lookup function used when a value is not found; may be overridden"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`MyEnum(..)` is handled by [`EnumMeta.__call__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/504b95047a8ada06ab630abce55ac2f85566ca37/Lib/enum.py#L265). You need to override that method:

```
from enum import EnumMeta, IntEnum


class DefaultEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    default = object()

    def __call__(cls, value=default, *args, **kwargs):
        if value is DefaultEnumMeta.default:
            # Assume the first enum is default
            return next(iter(cls))
        return super().__call__(value, *args, **kwargs)
        # return super(DefaultEnumMeta, cls).__call__(value, *args, **kwargs) # PY2


class MyEnum(IntEnum, metaclass=DefaultEnumMeta):
    # __metaclass__ = DefaultEnumMeta  # PY2 with enum34
    A = 0
    B = 1
    C = 2


assert MyEnum() is MyEnum.A
assert MyEnum(0) is MyEnum.A
assert MyEnum(1) is not MyEnum.A
```

Comment: Seems like serious overkill for such a simple problem.

Comment: @EthanFurman, Yes, it is. But I couldn't come up with a solution that satisfy `MyEnum() is MyEnum.A`

Comment: @EthanFurman I agree that this seems like serious overkill to solve this, but for my use-case, this is **way** cleaner than the alternative.

Answer (score 47):

[falsetru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867597/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-default-value-for-python-enums/44867928#44867928) would be the way to go if 0 argument case needs to be catered.

If it is only about returning default when given value does not exist, we can override `_missing_` hook in Enum class (Since [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/enum.html#supported-sunder-names)):

```
from enum import IntEnum


class MyEnum(IntEnum):
    A = 0
    B = 1
    C = 2

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        return cls.A

assert MyEnum(0) is MyEnum.A
assert MyEnum(1) is MyEnum.B
assert MyEnum(-1) is MyEnum.A
assert MyEnum(None) is MyEnum.A
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `_missing_` method. Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. `MyEnum()` still results in a `TypeError`. The goal was to be able to make an instance of `MyEnum` *without* providing a parameter.

Comment: Since EnumMeta ```__call__``` must take a positional argument, only way in that case is to define your metaclass, like what falsetru did.

Comment: Is `_missing_` a documented feature or just a hidden implementation detail? I mean is it possible that this behavior can change without any announcement in the future Python versions? I'm asking because of that *single* underscores around the name.

Comment: @Stephen why not put a default None for the value parameter?

Answer (score 8):

### *Update*

As of `aenum 2.2.1`<sup>1</sup> calling an Enum without a value is supported:

```
from aenum import Enum, no_arg

class Color(Enum):
    black = 0
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
    #
    @classmethod
    def _missing_value_(cls, value):
        if value is no_arg:
            return cls.black
```

and in use:

```
>>> Color(1)
<Color.red: 1>

>>> Color()
<Color.black: 0>

>>> Color(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: 4 is not a valid Color
```

---

### *Original Answer*

If you do not control the `Enum`s, then do:

```
my_val = list(MyEnum)[0]
```

or, if the `Enum` might be empty:

```
my_val = len(MyEnum) and list(MyEnum)[0] or None
```

If you do control the `Enum`s, then add a `get_default` method:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    def get_default(self):
        return self.A
```

or, even simpler, make `default` be an alias:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 0
    B = 1
    C = 2
    default = A
```

You could also wrap the first method in to a function:

```
def default_member(enum):
    return list(enum)[0]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: I'm familiar with the Enum API. I can see why you are suggesting these, but this doesn't actually answer my question does it ...

Comment: @Stephen:  falsetru already answered your exact question.  I'm offering alternative ways to get what you said you needed (a default member).

Comment: My bad. When I looked at this, I thought you had answered before falsetru. Your suggestions are valid if you are looking for ways set Enums to default values for cases where you don't need to call the Enum class without arguments.

Comment: @Stephen:  Thank you.  `falsetru`'s answer is the only way to solve your exact question; just be careful using/modifying metaclasses in general, and the `Enum` metaclass specifically;  I have it doing a lot behind the scenes to make everything work and I've seen casual modifications break resulting `Enum`s more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Why don’t you just use the [standard syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes)?

```
my_val = MyEnum.A
```

---

If you really want to do this, you may have to write your own enum meta override class.  You can see this example for the [implementation in cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/enum.py) so that you assign a default value equal to the first value in the value map for the enum.

Comment: I'm doing code generation in a metaclass and it would make things quite a bit simpler if I didn't have to know anything about the enum in order to make an instance of it.

Comment: @Stephen But wouldn't doing `MyEnum(default_value)` work? If you don't anything about the enum ahead of time, just get a default value from it.

Comment: @ChristianDean I want the author of the enum to specify the default. The metaclass won't know ahead of time what the default is.

Comment: There are also some other reasons why being able to call the Enum class without arguments will make things cleaner, hence my question.

Comment: @Stephen Can you post the code for your metaclass or an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if the code cannot be  taken out of context? If so, I think we can show you how to accomplish what your asking.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this problem. Posting my solution for Python 3.9.5

```
from enum import unique, Enum, EnumMeta

class PrinterModelMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __call__(cls, value=-1, *args, **kwargs):
        if value == -1:
            value = PrinterModel.detect_model()
        return super().__call__(value, *args, **kwargs)


@unique
class PrinterModel(Enum, metaclass=PrinterModelMeta):
    # FORBIDDEN = -1
    MODEL0 = 0
    MODEL1 = 1
    MODEL2 = 2

    @classmethod
    def detect_model(cls) -> int:
        model = None
        panel_name = cls.panel_name()
        if panel_name == "model-aaa":
            model = PrinterModel.MODEL0
        if panel_name == "model-bbb":
            model = PrinterModel.MODEL1
        if panel_name == "model-ccc":
            model = PrinterModel.MODEL2

        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        if model is None:
            raise UnknownPrinterModel()
        else:
            return model.value

    @classmethod
    def panel_name(cls) -> str:
        path = Path("/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-000f/of_node") / "panel-name"
        return path.read_text()[:-1] if path.exists() else None
```