# "Other"/Default-name behavior on a python Enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, enum-class

I'm trying to achieve the following behavior in a python "enum" (so far to no success):

Given the enum class

```
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    A=1
    B=2
    C=3
```

I want to have an "Other" member such that `MyEnum(5)` will be interpreted as "Other", while retaining the value 5, or,

```
>>> str(MyEnum(5))
... "<MyEnum.Other: 5>"
```

I thought of doing something along the line of overriding the `_missing_` function, but I don't know how to create a "custom" instance of `MyEnum` without rewriting `EnumMeta`.

Advices will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Following some comments that fail to understand my question precisely, I do not wish to have a default value for the enum, as this default value will not retain the value (that I wish to keep). I wish only that the value will be accepted with a default name.

Comment: That does not look like an application for `Enum`.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Why not? I'm trying to simplify the use of an internet enumerable set of constants, and have a default assignment given an unknown value. This allows for differentiating between known and unknown data in a simple and coherent way throughout the code, as well as allows for more encapsulated handling of unknown data (say, in a plugin or an outside module).

Comment: Check out [When and where to use Python Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22586895/208880).  It is possible to have a default [as shown in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44871907/208880), but the invalid/unknown code is not saved.

Comment: What you wrote could be accomplished simply by overriding the `_missing_` sunder method in Python 3.4+, but a nice answer nonetheless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to specify a default value for python enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867597/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-default-value-for-python-enums)

Comment: No, that's exactly what @EthanFurman referred me to. Anyway, I answered my own question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the saying goes, if you want something done... I created the following enum subclass (I didn't add any new members so that's allowed):

```
class DefaultNameEnum(Enum):
    """Support for "Other"/default-name values"""

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        possible_member = cls._value2member_map_.get(value, None)

        if possible_member is None:
            possible_member = cls._create_pseudo_member_(value)

        return possible_member

    @classmethod
    def _create_pseudo_member_(cls, value):
        """
        Create a default-name member.
        """

        default_member = cls._value2member_map_.get(None, None)

        if default_member is None:
            raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))

        # construct a singleton enum pseudo-member
        other_member = object.__new__(cls)
        other_member._name_ = default_member._name_
        other_member._value_ = value

        # use setdefault in case another thread already created a composite
        # with this value
        other_member = cls._value2member_map_.setdefault(value, other_member)

        return other_member

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Overrides the default implementation"""
        if isinstance(other, DefaultNameEnum):
            return self._name_ == other._name_
        return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other
```

This is based on the `Flag` enum subclass. Its usage is quite simple, actually - Just define as `None` whichever name you wish to have as your default. It is best illustrated using an example - consider the class:

```
class ABC(DefaultNameEnum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3

    Other = None
```

Than, the following console calls will give:

> ```
> >>> print([repr(mem) for mem in ABC])    
> ... ['<ABC.A: 1>', '<ABC.B: 2>', '<ABC.C: 3>', '<ABC.Other: None>']
> >>> ABC(123)
> ... '<ABC.Other: 123>'
> >>> ABC(1) == ABC(2)
> ... False
> >>> ABC(123) == ABC.Other
> ... True
> >>> ABC(123) == ABC(1374)
> ... True
> ```

If you wish to take this implementation and use it, note the following points:

1. The behavior in the last line might be wanted and might not - depending on your usage. If this is an unwanted usage, just change the `__eq__` method to compare names when either `self._value_` or `other._value_` are `None`.
2. If you use this class, for the sake of representability you might wish for the default value's `__repr__` to output `'<ABC.Other>'` rather than `'<ABC.Other: None>'` in the case of `None` value. This could easily be accomplished by overriding the `__repr__` method.
3. If you don't define a default member, the class will raise an exception upon calling it upon an unknown value (just like any `Enum` subclass).

I also wish to note that in the above implementation I would've preferred to use a sunder member such as `_default_name_` or `_default_value_member_` rather than assigning `None`, but alas the `enum` module does not permit defining a new sunder member for `Enum` subclasses.

Comment: Kudos!  I appreciate that  your solution does not involve messing with `EnumMeta`.  The docstring for `_create_pseudo_member_` is not correct, though.  Also, I don't understand how you would have used `_default_value_`?  (Note: you could have used a single leading underscore.)

Comment: You are correct about the docstring - I just took the `Flag`'s class implementation of this class as a basis (and hence the last line in this function which I guess solves a bug which I don't understand). I altered the docstring. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding `_default_value_`, I should've used a different naming, so I renamed these in the answer to perhaps clarify better. Two possibilities of additional members come to mind - either `_default_name_` that would contain a string representing the name of the "Other"-member; or `_default_value_member_` (again, not a good naming) that would contain the value whose enum-label should be the "Other"-label. For example, in this case, add `_default_value_member_=None`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you're asking for:

```
>>> class Yep(enum.IntFlag):
...  A = 1
...  B = 2
... 
>>> Yep(5)
<Yep.4|A: 5>
```

So, `Yep(5)` is *valid*, but there won't be a `Yep.Other` magic member.

Comment: I thought of something of the sort (even though I don't want to restrict myself to integer values), but then I lose the equality-comparison and representabilty features.

Comment: @EZLearner, equality comparison works fine: `Yep(5) == Yep(5)`

Comment: Yes, but what I meant is to check if two different "Other"s are similar, and that doesn't happen here