# Assigning a default value to an enum class when the value provided to the constructor is not enumerated

Tags: python

I have an enum class:

```
import enum

class Version(enum.IntEnum):
    VERSION_1 = 1
    VERSION_2 = 2
    VERSION_UNKNOWN = 99
```

When a user initializes the enum class with a value that is not listed as a class field, I would like him to get VERSION_UNKNOWN i.e. the following snippet to execute successfully:

```
e = enum(3)
assert e == Version.VERSION_UNKNOWN
```

Is there any way to do that sort of thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to specify a default value for python enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867597/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-default-value-for-python-enums)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think the enum build-in `_missing_` is your friend: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum._missing_

```py
import enum

class Version(enum.IntEnum):
    VERSION_1 = 1
    VERSION_2 = 2
    VERSION_UNKNOWN = 99

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        return Version.VERSION_UNKNOWN
```

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for. Initially I typed it with double underscores.